# excel formatting: show percent value without percent sign

Tags: excel

I'd like to show numbers such as 0.95 as 95 in excel; formatting them as % shows me 95%; but I'd like to get rid of the percent sign. Is there something I can do in "Custom Formatting" for this?
Note: I'd prefer not to do something like cell content * 100 etc..but instead use a custom formatter

Thanks

Comment: Don't hack Excel like this; it doesn't support such things for good reason: just multiply by 100. Nothing wrong with the question though, plus one.

Comment: How much is 2 times 2? Is it 4, 0.04 or 0.0004? (Just trying to make you understand how dangerous it might be messing with numbers like that)

Answer (score 10):

You can make it look like you want while keeping the underlying value.

This is a hacky method"

1. Enable `Wrap Text` on the cells.
2. You want a Custom Format.
3. Enter the custom format as follows:

> 1. Enter `0.00`
> 2. While holding down Alt, enter 0010. This will put in a line break
> 3. Put in the %.
> 4. Hit OK

This will put the number in percentage mode but the `%` will be on the second line.  With the cell set as wrap and the cell only tall enough to show one line it will only show the number.

The underlying number will remain the `.xxxx` and not that of `100 * .xxxx`

[image]

Comment: did not realize it would be that much of a pain...I was looking to have some magic custom formatting..Thanks

Comment: Plus one for evil genius.

Comment: You can use `Ctrl`+`J` to place a line break into the Custom Number format instead of the `Alt`+`0010` code

Comment: This answer and the ctrl+j ^ is a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the percent sign in the formula, this way you can format the cell(s) as Number, and have a clean numbers which you could also use as whole numbers if need be.

Supposing the data column is B, my formula in D1, for example, would be:

(A1 * B1%) / C1

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Format cell as a number and then put % at the end of your division formula. Then click on cell to move decimals over to the amount you want. Example:

Number format cell
=159.38/168%
move decimal over until number is displayed
I was able to do this and get the cell to show 94.9

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort of convoluted way. My downloaded output has the % sign. I want to make a chart without the percent sign so I need whole numbers. To do that:

1. Change all the cells from Percentage to General. Now you have decimals.
2. Decrease all the cells to 2 decimal places (for whole numbers).
3. Now comes the annoying part of typing in the whole numbers in each cell to replace the decimal. (However, it's already rounded for you so hopefully that minimizes error. This is the not so quick part if you have a large dataset.)
4. Once you have all your whole numbers, decrease all the cells to 0 decimal places and voila, percent numbers without percent signs.

11% >> .11 >> 11.00 >> 11

That's just one simpleton's solution. Hope it helps!