# Excel VBA : format to percentage without percentage sign

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting, percentage

To keep the question as simple as possible:

In excel cell A1 has a numeric value: `0.11`

I want to format the cell to percentage value but without the % sign.
I want: `11` ; not `11%`

**I am not asking how to do this in regular excel; it must be VBA.**.

I guess `Range("A1").NumberFormat = ....` is the way to go; but when using this method, the % sign always show up.

Is there a way to format this without the percentage sign?
*Note that the value can not be changed, it has to remain 0.11 .*

Comment: There is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514785/excel-formatting-show-percent-value-without-percent-sign!).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel formatting: show percent value without percent sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514785/excel-formatting-show-percent-value-without-percent-sign)

Comment: Not a duplicate: I can do this without VBA. This question is how to do it with VBA.

Comment: I don't see any VBA in that post.

Comment: oops apologies, I mis-read that as want to achieve this without VBA. Removed the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround would be to display the content of your cell x 100.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A:A")   ' Change with your Range
        If cell.Value > 0 Then
            cell.NumberFormat = Str(cell.Value * 100)
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

This would work but would have to be rerun with every change. For example with the following code in your Worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then 
       Call Macro1            
   End If

End Sub

Sub Macro1()

        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In Range("A:A")   ' Change with your Range
            If cell.Value > 0 Then
                cell.NumberFormat = Str(cell.Value * 100)
            End If
        Next cell

    End Sub
```

Comment: This comes very, very close to what I initially wanted. It solved te problem I was working on, so I'll mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Range("A5").NumberFormat = "0.00" & Chr(10) & "%"
Range("A5").WrapText = True
```

Comment: This is a very nice workaround; but it is not a solution. Because when you enlarge the cell, the % still shows up.  For printing this will work, so it is a good quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a workaround but try this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long
Dim STRNG As String

For i = 2 To Range("A1").Height / 11.25
    STRNG = STRNG & Chr(10)
Next i
Debug.Print STRNG
Range("A1").NumberFormat = STRNG & "0" & Chr(10) & "%"

End Sub
```

It will look at the cells height and will calculate how many linebreaks you need to hide the "%" sign.

You might want to add on it, like call it upon sheet change event and instead of looking at only cell A1 then loop from A1 to A & Lastrow.....

Or assign it to a button offcourse

Answer (score 0):

This will work as requested:

```
Private Sub remove_percent(where As Range)

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In where
        If (cell.NumberFormat = "0.00") Then
            cell = Round(cell * 100, 0)
            cell.NumberFormat = "0"

            ' if we exceed 100%, let's round it to 100
            If (cell > 100) Then
                cell = 100
            End If     
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

You can then invoke it in the following way *(as an example):*

```
Call remove_percent(Range("A1:A5"))
```

Comment: @Oak what would be the expected result if the cell contains eg `14.24` ? `1424` or? With `0.11` it's kinda clear. In other words, **should this only apply to cells that begin with `0`?**

Comment: In my case 14.24 would not be possible; the maximum value in the cell is 1; meaning 100%; but in this case I would only want to see 100; not 100%.

Comment: Alright, hopefully my last edit now. Check if it works as it should now. Keep in mind this code expects input range of `#.##` format. If you want it to 'eat up' anything, simply remove the `if` condition in the beginning

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but your edit still changes the value that is in the cell.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think it's really possible without artificially changing the value. You either need to use a formula + format, or implicitly transform the value to an integerized percentagte (*100). Essentially, **Excel doesn't even want to let you do it, because it goes against the rules of math. `11% !== 11` but `0.11`** So it seems, artificially adjusting the value is necessary here